# call asp.net button click from onbeforeunload javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, validation

my iframe content aspx page contain 3 asp element: textbox, requriedfieldValidator realated to the textbox and button ,
in javascript onbeforeunload I want to call the button click event that have prevent leave the page if the textbox is empty.

but the folowing code dosent work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
document.getElementById("Button1").click();
}
</script>
<asp:textbox runat='server' id="TextBox1" AutoPostBack="true"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="TextBox1_Click" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"    ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: dosent work? the textbox is empty in "onbeforeunload" so the validator stop the click call

Comment: I want to stop the unload and show the validation message ,any way to do this?

Comment: @mich I've edited my answer to explain the security hazard related to the behavior you desire.

Answer (score 0):

`onbeforeunload` event handler is special. You can't unconditionally prevent the user from leaving the page.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload
You should return non-void value from this handler - preferably `string` - the user will be prompted if he/she really want's to leave the page. Most of the browsers will present the returned string in the popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    return "The textbox is empty. Are you sure you wan't to leave the page?";
}
</script>
```

The reason for such unusual behavior is security. User has to be informed that the navigation to another page is interrupted. Otherwise he/she may think that the navigation succeeded.
Imagine that you silently cancel the navigation inside this handler and you change the content of the page to look like Internet banking application. There is a vary small chance that the user actually wanted to visit the banking application. But it may happen. This opens the gate to hijacking user's credentials. So it's not possible in web browser.

Basically inside `onbeforeunload` event handler all the actions, that would normally stop the navigation to another page, take no effect - they are ignored and this is intentional.

Comment: But then the client can click OK and leave the page.

Comment: Yes, and you can't do nothing about it. The user controls the browser and always has the possibility to leave the page.